# Why Javascript sticky header doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a website with a sticky header and it worked well. Some other people worked with it too and they made some changes, but now the stickiness of the header doesn't work. I tried to put back the old code but It didn't help.

```js
var modalBtn = document.querySelector(".cta-add"),
  modalBg = document.querySelector(".modal-bg"),
  modalClose = document.querySelector(".modal-close");
modalBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modalBg.classList.add("bg-active");
  }),
  modalClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modalBg.classList.remove("bg-active");
  }),
  $("#booknow")
  .on("click", function() {
    $.getScript("https://fareharbor.com/embeds/api/v1/?autolightframe=yes");
  })
  .done(function() {
    window.location.href =
      "https://fareharbor.com/embeds/book/.../items/148437/?full-items=yes&flow=no";
  });

$("#contact").on("click", function() {
    $.getScript("headers.php?file=recaptcha.js");
  }),
  (window.onscroll = myFunction);
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader"),
  sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.pageYOffset > sticky);
}

function openTab(e, t) {
  var n, c, a;
  for (
    c = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent"), n = 0; n < c.length; n++
  )
    c[n].style.display = "none";
  for (
    a = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"), n = 0; n < a.length; n++
  )
    a[n].className = a[n].className.replace(" active", "");
  (document.getElementById(t).style.display = "block"),
  (e.currentTarget.className += " active");
}
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger"),
  navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links"),
  links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
var mylogo = document.getElementById("myLogo");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open"),
      links.forEach((e) => {
        e.classList.toggle("fade");
      });
  }),
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hamburgerID").on("click", function() {});
  }),
  $(".nav-links li a").on("click", function() {
    $("#hamburgerID").click();
  });
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```

I implemented this in my old code, and it is working. My question is what else can cause this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet to reproduce the problem (because it is working for me when I copy / paste)

Comment: If I may I have a few comments about your code. why don't you replace `(window.onscroll = function () { myFunction(); });` by `window.onscroll = myFunction;`. Also `window.pageYOffset > sticky ? header.classList.add("sticky") : header.classList.remove("sticky");` could be re-write `header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.pageYOffset > sticky)` finally why don't use CSS [`position: sticky`](https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky) it is very well suported

Comment: I added the full JS code.

Comment: It looks like the header doesn't because of the booknow modalBtn.addEventListener but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the modalBtn.addEventListener function to this:

```
modalClose.addEventListener('click',function(){
    modalBg.classList.remove('bg-active');
  });
```

It is good now, but If someone could tell me what was the problem with the old code I would be grateful.